# Regex for finding between 1 and 3 character in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex which should return true, if [A-Za-z] is occured between 1 and 3, but I am not able to do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "(?:([A-Za-z]*){3}).*";
    String regex1 = "(?=((([A-Za-z]){1}){1,3})).*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AD1CDD").find());
}
```

Note: for consecutive 3 characters I am able to write it, but what I want to achieve is the occurrence should be between 1 and 3 only for the entire string. If there are 4 characters, it should return false. I have used look-ahead to achieve this

Comment: Could you add some inputs and outputs for better understanding.

Comment: Try `^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z](?!(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){3})`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/a0eZx2/1

Comment: Try [`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){4}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/exEl6u/1)

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with `str.matches("[a-zA-Z]{1,3}")`?

Comment: @shmosel It only matches consecutive character but my string can have character anywhere.

Comment: @revo provided regex solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: So you want to return false if any char exists more than 3 times and the string consists at least of 1 char?

Comment: @revo this can be done more easily without the negative lookahead, as a positive statement.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The negative lookahead satisfies much more sooner than your proposed one. Compare engine steps [here](https://regex101.com/r/d4PBkf/1) with [yours](https://regex101.com/r/9VGg13/1). [16 vs 83]

Comment: @Anony-Mousse OP only needs to return true or false. To compete it you need to use atomic groups and not capturing groups.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I suggest to use a for loop with a break, if you need efficiency. The number of steps depends on your regexp engine. You can also flag to disable backtracking IIRC.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse To avoid backtracks you need to use atomic groups (as I mentioned earlier). Yet negative lookahead (if available) fails fast on invalid subjects (regardless of regex flavor).

Comment: And when you have catastrophic backtracking problems (I don't think it will be catastrophic here, just linear), it usually just means you are badly abusing regexp and should rather use more appropriate code. Because of readability and maintenance I'd also rather avoid regexps here.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse This is a trivial task for regular expressions and actually they are made for it. You only have to know it or ask someone who knows. Your second proposed regex `^(([^A-Za-z]+|)[A-Za-z]){1,3}[^A-Za-z]*$` (which you have removed) in no way is more performant than the former (you probably have this in mind when you were going to remove).

Comment: Yes, I applied the wrong technique. Use `*+`, i.e. `^(?:[^A-Za-z]*+[A-Za-z]){1,3}[^A-Za-z]*+$` if you really want to do premature optimization and ruin readability. **The for loop will still win.**

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Why should you insist on using possessive quantifiers / atomic groups which are hardly supported in regex engines and deny the fact that a simple negative lookahead could do the job better?

Comment: Because its unreadable. Give your regexp to the average developer. He will fail at decrypting it. My version *much* more clearly communicates the intuition of 1 to 3 times. Yes, "once, but not three additional times" is the same, but cryptic. And that is a high price to pay. The "possessive" extension is only necessary for backtracking engines, and just an optimization that I do not consider necessary.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse So I see that your reasoning is not technical. As long as a possessive quantifier in your regex needs explaining, a negative lookahead in the other regex needs too.

Comment: Yes, again: I do not suggest to use it. Clearly, the asker is not an expert on lookaheads or possessive quantifiers, right? That is just for regexp101 step counting microbenchmarkers like you. My suggestion is the for loop below, or the simplest  regexp that gets the job done, not the most overoptimized expert variant.

Comment: And again your reasoning is not technical and I like that you mentioned me in your first comment to bring up an attention and later forgot about it.

Comment: I do consider maintenance and readability of code to be technical. They are not artwork. And where did I "forget about" what? Right from the beginning I have been mentioning that an easier (no negative lookaheads) approach exists. Your only defense is that it is faster - but then the for loop wins, and likely performance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if

- 1 to 3 characters of the range [a-zA-Z] are in the string
- Any other character can occur arbitrary often?

First of all, just counting the characters and *not* using a regular expression is more efficient, as this is not a regular language problem, but a trivial counting problem. There is nothing wrong with using a `for` loop for this problem (except that interpreters such as Python and R can be fairly slow).

Nevertheless, you can (ab-) use extended regular expressions:

```
^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){1,3}[^A-Za-z]*$
```

This is fairly straightforward, once you also model the "other" characters. And that is what you should do to define a pattern: model all accepted strings (i.e. the entire "language"), not only those characters you want to find.

Alternatively, you can "findAll" matches of `([A-Za-z])`, and look at the length of the result. This may be more convenient if you also need the actual characters.

The for loop would look something like this:

```
public static boolean containsOneToThreeAlphabetic(String str) {
    int matched = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if ((c>='A' && c<='Z') || (c>='a' && c<='z')) matched++;
    }
    return matched >=1 && matched <= 3;
}
```

This is straightforward, readable, extensible, and efficient (in compiled languages). You can also add a `if (matched>=4) return false;` (or `break`) to stop early.

Comment: Why not make the capturing group a *non capture* `(?:` and further I don't think it's abuse of regex. Best answer.

Comment: You can, but it makes the regexp even harder to read. If you want to be fast, use the for loop. So no use in optimizing the regexp. **Regular languages are not meant to count**, that is why I consider this to be an abuse of regexps. Because the `{1,3}` construct is an extension beyond regular languages. For three, you could of course materialize this into an actual DFA without counting.

Comment: If you want to make it more regular and/or fast, you can blow this up to `^[^A-Za-z]*+[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*+(?:[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*+(?:[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*+)?)?$` for example.

Comment: Point noted regarding for-loop and use of regex to achieve this. I asked this question because I was trying to achieve it using regex and not successful in that. So, I was just curious to know how this can be achieved using regex

Answer (score -1):

Please, stop playing with regex, you'll complicate not only your own life, but the life of the people, who have to handle your code in the future. Choose a simpler approach, find all `[A-Za-z]+` strings, put them into the list, then check every string, if the length is within 1 and 3 or beyond that.

Answer (score -2):

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/RU260c/4)

`/([A-Za-z])(?=(?:.*\1){3})/s`

Looking for a char and for 3 repetitions of it. So if it matches there are 4 or more equal chars present.

Comment: OP wants **no more** than 3

Comment: @lenik i know, this one matches if you have any char occuring 4 or more times. so if it doesnt match, there are no 4 or more - so you will have to negate the result and you are golden :) - fixed to > 3 - ty :)

Comment: This will match `////`.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse `[A-z]` is `/` in? I dont see where it matches `////` please explain

Comment: Check the ASCII character set.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Check the link, i dont get it. - Tested it, doesnt match :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\\\\ `. Check the ASCII table yourself on which characters are between `A` and `z`.

Comment: Also, the poster probably wanted to match `A B 1 C` positively.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse aye ok didnt know regex includes chars inbetween, thank you, corrected it :) `A B 1 C` is a positive match, since the regex is looking for the ones we dont want. If it doesnt match, everything is fine.

Comment: But you are only considering exact repetitions. `ABCABC` and the empty string do not satisfy his conditions. You got don't properly test the negative either.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Seems like i misunderstood the question. I wanted to test if there are chars occuring more than 3 times. But the question acually asks for all chars which occur 1-3 times so on a String `aaaabbbccd`(order doesnt matter) the result should be `[b,c,d]` right?

Comment: As I understand the question, the strings must have 1 to 3 alphabetic characters plus any non alphabetic.